# Хранить много View как глобальные переменные

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот у меня в приложении около 400 View, приложение состоит из 1 activity, где все окна(RelativeLayout) с элементами подключены через include. Все эти 400 View я храню в отдельном классе как глобальные переменные, и сразу инициализирую. Вопрос в том, на сколько это плохо, как много съедает памяти и критично ли это? 
Просто еще можно было во всех местах программы, где обращаемся к view-ам, делать их как локальная переменная и по несколько а то и 10 раз раз писать к примеру:
RL_miniMenu = (RelativeLayout) mapsActivity.findViewById(R.id.RL_miniMenu)..

Как лучше из этих двух вариантов?

Answer (score 1):

Тут есть как минимум 2 момента, считающихся очень плохой практикой

1) RealativeLayout в 99% случаях не нужен. Он едва ли не самый медленный из лайаутов и имеет весьма спорный функционал. Скорее всего можно избавиться от нескольких вложенных друг в друга лайаутов и заменить их одним ConstrainLayout. Крайне рекомендую озаботится этим вопросом

2) 400 разных лайаутов явно не уместятся на одном экране. Но если они у вас "заинклюжены" в один файл, то как только этот файл "надувается" все эти объекты отрисовываются в растровую картинку и хранятся в оперативной памяти. То есть сотни элементов, которые не видны, хранятся  в памяти в виде отрендереной совершенно бесполезной картинки. Это расточительство. Вам определенно нужны списки с переиспользованием View или фрагменты. Точнее смогу подсказать только если расскажете что именно вы делаете с этими элементами

Постоянные findViewById тоже недешевая вещь. Не критично дорогая, но зачем делать ее дважды, если можно только единожды? Эта проблема тоже решается через  RecyclerView или другие элементы с переиспользованием View

Хранить 400 ссылок на вьюшки в некотором классе не страшно, если это не статические переменные.

Если дополните вопрос о целях вашего приложения - дайте знать, дополню ответ

Comment: У меня построен интерфейс программы, что вместо фрагментов или новых activity используются RealativeLayout с match_parent, а в них уже другие элементы.. 400 это всего элементов, а самих RealativeLayout может 30, и все они изначально установлены в Gone, и показываются и закрываются по одному/два, в зависимости от действий пользователя. Например открыть окно со списком маркеров, или открыть окно редактирования, открыть окно добавления маркера и тд.. Я думал если visibility="gone", то они не в памяти.. Одновременно открыто не больше трех таких окон из RealativeLayout .

Comment: С visibility=gone объект не рендерится, по крайней мере не должен. Не удивлюсь, если у какого-нибудь ZTE это не так. Чтоб такой проблемы избежать используейте androidx или support компоненты. Ваш подход работоспособен, ничего криминального в нем нет, но им пользовались году в 2010. Сейчас есть ряд инструментов, упрощающих жизнь в таких ситуациях, и я бы рекомендовал вам с ними ознакомится. Ну, и RelativeLayout лучше выпилить, это не сложно. часто его можно заменить на FrameLayout без проблем, если нет - ConstraintLayout

Comment: Из примеров проблем: представьте что юзер повернул экран в портретный режим. У вас будет одна единственная функция, которая должна состояние всех вьюшек уместить в ограниченный по размеру bundle. Такое себе удовольствие. Ну, и кода придется каким-то неведомым образом организовывать. Если у вас 30 разных экранов, то на каждом своя логика, видимо. И она вся перемешается в общих местах, читать будет очень сложно